# Tomcat complains of a memory leak with spring integration while shutting down

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting the following error while shutting down tomcat

> SEVERE: The web application [/TestService] appears to have started a thread named [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

```xml
<gateway id="testGateway" service-interface="org.example.TestGateway"
         default-request-channel="requestChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"/>

public interface TestGateway {
 Future execute(Request request);
}

<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="routerChannelA">
    <int:service-activator ...
    <int:transformer ....
</int:chain>

<int:router input-channel="routerChannelA" expression="payload.name" resolution-required="true">
    <int:mapping value="B" channel="channelB" />
    ....
</int:router>

<int:chain input-channel="channelB" output-channel="channelD">
    <int:transformer ......
    <int:gateway request-channel="channelC" .....
    <int:filter expression="headers['RELEASE'] != null" discard-="nullChannel"/>
</int:chain>

<int:recipient-list-router id="customRouter" input-channel="channelD"
        timeout="1234"
        ignore-send-failures="true"
        apply-sequence="false" >
         <int:recipient channel="splitterRequestChannel"/>
        <int:recipient channel="completeChannel"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:splitter expression="payload" input-channel="splitterRequestChannel" 
                output-channel="splitterResponseChannel" ></int:splitter>

<int:channel id="splitterResponseChannel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="splitterChannelTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="splitterChannelTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" >
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="daemon" value="false"/>
</bean> 

<int:chain input-channel="splitterResponseChannel">
    ......
    ......
</int:chain>
```

1. The client sends requests to TestGateway. I dont have to send any reply back to client, but I want to return back immediately.
   The Future return type serves my purpose of returning immediately. However I feel it blocks the main thread.
2. The request moves from a series of chains and finally reaches splitterRequestChannel. This channel delegates its work to the threads initiated by splitterChannelTaskExecutor, they do their respective jobs now. I feel the main thread should be released now as it has delegated its task, but it doesn't look its getting released.

**Edit:**

```
 public interface TestGateway {
     void execute(Request request);
    }

    <bean id="requestChannelTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" >
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="daemon" value="false"/>
   </bean>  
   <int:channel id="requestChannel">
   <int:dispatcher task-executor="requestChannelTaskExecutor"/>
   </int:channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

1. Just return void if you don't care about the result.
2. How are you instantiating the application context? If using normal spring web, spring should take care of closing the context; if you are creating it yourself, it's up to you to close it.
3. Take a thread dump to see what the thread is doing.

**EDIT:**

If your flow never returns a reply, the TE within the gateway is stuck waiting for the reply.

So; return `void` and you won't have the problem.

Comment: In addition to Gary's answer and your question: to return immedietely from the one-way gateway and process the downstream flow asynchronisly you should make the gateway's `request-channel` as an `ExecutorChanlel` or `QueueChannel` and don't worry about timeout.

Comment: 1) I tried making the method void, associating the requestChannel with a task executor(for handling multiple simultaneous requests) - but even then the thread wasn't released. 3) what do I use for thread dump, do you suggest anything?

Comment: Please show your configuration (edit the question). Without a `Future` return type, that task executor within the gateway should not get any tasks.

Comment: Finally, you can also add `reply-timeout="0"` to the gateway so, again, it won't wait for a reply.